# Randomly selecting a row for a specific column from CSV

Tags: javascript, csv, sahi

I have a function called enterInformation(); with parameters that I want pulled in from a CSV file. The way I have my CSV file is it has about 12 columns and the first row is the TITLE/HEADER for what each column is. The way I have my script right now is it is always pulling the first line in the CSV file and I do not want that because it is the title/headers and I also want it to pick a random row when inputting text fields.

How would I go about having my function enter field information by randomly picking a value from the data set I created (also ignoring the first line if that's possible)?

Here is my snippet of where I am calling the function:

```
for (var $i=0; $i<$data.length; $i++) {
    var $row = $data[$i];
    try {
        enterInformation($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3]);
    } catch (e) {
        _logException(e);
    }
    break;
}
```

Here is my global function:

```
 function enterInformation($entityType, $entityName, $address1, $city) {
     _click(_link("Select Entity"));
     _click(_listItem($entityType));
     _setValue(_textbox("entityName"), $entityName);
     _setValue(_textbox("address1"), $address1);
     _setValue(_textbox("city"), $city);
     _click(_submit("Continue"));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about picking the row you want to use for values?

```
// -1 excludes the header from the count, +1 skips the header
var rowForValues = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($data.length - 1)) + 1;
var $row = $data[rowForValues];
enterInformation($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3]);
```

Or bake it into your loop, if you like.

Comment: This solution is actually very acceptable for my request. Thank you so much. While I am still wanting to learn how to have it randomly pick it for me without defining the row, this method you provided me will make my life easier for my web automation either way and it will definitely be used for other testing scenarios (now I know how to define what row I want to use and ignore the first row). Thanks again!